# How to mount a iSCSI/SAN storage drive to a stable device name (one that can't change on re-connect)?

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6, fstab

We need stable device paths for our Twinstrata SAN drives.  Many guides for setting up iSCSI connectors simply say to use a device path like `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`.

This is far from correct, I doubt that any setup exists that would be happy to have its device name suddenly change (from `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdb` for example).

The fix I found was to install `multipath` and start a `multipathd` on boot which then provides a stable mapping between the storage's WWID to a device path like this `/dev/mapper/firebird_database`.  This is a method described in the CentOS/RedHat here: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/DM_Multipath/setup_procedure.html.

This seems a little complicated though.  We noticed that it is common to see UUIDs appear in fstab on new installs.  So, the question is, why do we need an external program (`multipathd`) running to provide a stable device mount?  Should there be a way to provide the WWID directly in `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert and am also exploring this area, and I think you can try mapping the device to the LUNs, which is fixed.

This can be found under /dev/disk/by-path .

Do this to see the links between the LUNs and the mapped devices:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-path
```

To find out more about the iSCSI disks:

```
fdisk -l /dev/disk/by-path/*
```

Hope this helps!